# async.map not calling callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm trying to use the [async.js map function](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map). However, when I run the following script, the callback in the third argument is never invoked. The console only prints `END`. The iteratee however does get invoked.

```
const async = require('async');

async.map([1,2,3,4,5], n => n+1, (err, res) => {
    err ? console.log('Error: ' + err) : console.log(res);
});

console.log('END');
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async.js` expects the iteratee function to be *async*, otherwise it won't work as expected:

```js
async.map([1,2,3,4,5], async n => n+1, (err, res) => {
    err ? console.log('Error: ' + err) : console.log(res);
});
console.log('END');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.6.1/async.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense... and I didn't know that you can use ES async functions as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling done callback within the iteratee

```
async.map([1,2,3,4,5], (n, done) => done(null, n+1), (err, res) => {
    err ? console.log('Error: ' + err) : console.log(res);
});
```

> An async function to apply to each item in coll. The iteratee should
>   complete with the transformed item. Invoked with (item, callback).

Comment: Argh... makes sense :-D Thank you!